# invalid initializer for structured binding declaration

Tags: c++, stdtuple, structured-bindings

How should I fix this error? Should I use a `const std::tuple<int, int, char>` instead?

```
constexpr auto [ Y_AxisLen, X_AxisLen, fillCharacter ] { 36, 168, ' ' };
```

This gives errors like:

```
error: structured binding declaration cannot be 'constexpr'
  434 |         constexpr auto [ Y_AxisLen, X_AxisLen, fillCharacter ] { 36, 168, ' ' };

 error: invalid initializer for structured binding declaration
  434 |         constexpr auto [ Y_AxisLen, X_AxisLen, fillCharacter ] { 36, 168, ' ' };
```

`Y_AxisLen` and `X_AxisLen` should be of type `int` and `fillCharacter` should be a `char`.

Comment: Well the first error message is pretty clear, you can't use `constexpr` here. Why do you need these values to be `constexpr`? Perhaps it's enough to make them `const`?

Comment: @Some programmer dude Switching to `const` won't make a difference. Only the first error will disappear.

Comment: And why do you need structured binding here instead of e.g. plain and simple `constexpr int Y_AxisLen = 36, X_AxisLen = 168; constexpr char fillCharacter = ' ';`? Don't overthink your code, or use new features just because they're new. :)

Comment: @Some programmer dude Yeah, that's a valid choice. I just wanted the code to be a little bit more compact.

Comment: Compactness is not a goal for any project. Whether you write this or the long variant, you can be the compiler will generate the same exact thing.

Comment: Brevity is usually not a good goal in programming. Readability, the ability to clearly convey meaning, and maintainability are much more important. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- structure binding isn't allowed to be `constexpr` now.
- structure binding can only be applied to the following cases.

  - array
  - tuple-like
  - structure data members

ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

If you must use structure binding, use `std::make_tuple`

```cpp
const auto [ Y_AxisLen, X_AxisLen, fillCharacter ] = std::make_tuple(36, 168, ' ');
```